# CKAN docker compose with custom extensions

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, ckan

I have been trying to customize the default CKAN docker image to include my prefered extensions. The problem is that the precedence of installing pip packages, configuring the ini files and, building and running the main CKAN image is not clear for me.
I have tried adding a layer to the Dockerfile (see below) but extensions are not available after running `docker-compose up`. The `add-extensions.sh` file contains pip install commands for each extension.

`RUN sh $CKAN_VENV/src/ckan/contrib/docker/add-extensions.sh`

I have also tried to include my commands in the docker-compose file itself, inside the ckan service, as follows.

```
command: >
      sh -c "
            pip install ckanext-geoview && 
            pip install ckanext-datarequests && 
            ckan config-tool "/etc/ckan/production.ini" -f "/etc/ckan/custom-config.ini" && 
            ckan config-tool "/etc/ckan/production.ini" -s app:main -e ckan.plugins='stats text_view image_view recline_view datastore datapusher resource_proxy geo_view datarequests' && 
            ckan -c /etc/ckan/production.ini run --host 0.0.0.0"
```

But this is not working either. So what is the recommended way of including custom plugins inside the default CKAN image?

Comment: Can you add a link to the docker-compose repo you are using?

Comment: Yes. It is the original CKAN repo in github. https://github.com/ckan/ckan

Comment: What error message are you getting? According to Open Knowledge [CKAN Dockerfile](https://github.com/okfn/docker-ckan/blob/master/ckan/Dockerfile), this is the correct way of adding extensions to your CKAN instance